# authentication or decryption has failed when sending mail to GMail using SSL

Tags: c#, email, mono, gmail

I'm referring to this [guide on C# SMTP mail](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm).

Here is my code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("dave.stockinger@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("dave.stockinger@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyUserNameInGmail", "MyGmailPassWord");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Unfortunately, there's an exception regarding SSL and I can't fix it:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Message
>   could not be sent. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: The
>   authentication or decryption has
>   failed. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: SSL
>   authentication error:
>   RemoteCertificateNotAvailable,
>   RemoteCertificateChainErrors   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.m__4
>   (System.Object sender,
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
>   certificate,
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
>   chain, SslPolicyErrors
>   sslPolicyErrors) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream+c__AnonStorey7.<>m__A
>   (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
>   cert, System.Int32[] certErrors)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.OnRemoteCertificateValidation
>   (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
>   certificate, System.Int32[] errors)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.RaiseRemoteCertificateValidation
>   (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
>   certificate, System.Int32[] errors)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.RaiseServerCertificateValidation
>   (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
>   certificate, System.Int32[]
>   certificateErrors) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates
>   (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection
>   certificates) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process
>   ()   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage
>   (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream
>   handMsg) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback
>   (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000]
>   in :0    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback
>   (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000]
>   in :0    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send
>   (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>   at csharpdungeon.MainClass.Main ()
>   [0x00000] in :0

Comment: someone already implemented sending via gmail (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct solution is not to remove SSL Certificate Validation. GMail has a valid certificate. The problem is that Mono can't seem to find the certificate.

This is completely wrong for so many reasons, but mainly because it removes a very important certificate validation:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
            delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
                { return true; };
```

The correct solution is to install the certificate in your machine:

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove --machine
certmgr -ssl smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465
```

This will effectively download the certificate for gmail and it will make it available for mono to use.

Comment: Is there any way to import the certificates as we go ?

I am writing a crawler, and I need to import the certificates to the mono store as I reach them.

Comment: Will `certmgr -ssl smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465` blindly allow whatever certificate it receives - and expose it to a MITM problem?

Comment: @TonoNam I know it's late, but now it is

Answer (score 23):

Check if code below would work for you; I've tested it on my gmail account and it seem to work fine with my mono 2.0 running on ubuntu 10.04LTS

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace mono_gmail
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress("my.name@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("my.name@hotmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpServer.Port = 587;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my.name", "my.password");
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
                delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
                    { return true; };
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

solution is taken from [here](http://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/mono-c-sending-mail-through-gmail/)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: The code is actually ignoring certificate errors, not good for security.

Comment: -1: This code is wrong, because it doesn't solve the problem of CAs not being recognized. They are still not being recognized and now you have opened up your application to massive MITM problems.

Answer (score 6):

You do not have the appropriate certificate authorities installed somewhere where Mono can see them.  Please have a look at [the Mono project security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security) for the steps to remedy this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SSL rather than TLS, you need port 465 rather than 587.

See http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the port, I know the default SMTP port for SSL is 465

Comment: Yes, but it changes from "crashes" to "freezes"

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution from  [SmtpClient with Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801224/smtpclient-with-gmail)

```
certmgr -ssl smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465
```

If you are running mono web server, run command with same username as mono process.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to send securely with SSL? You could remove this statement `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;` which would not require the SSL cert.