# Sending Email By Using C# in unity3D?

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine

I need to send an email by using C# in Unity3D. I have done this but suffer from a Runtime Warning. Please help me solve the below warning.

warning:The class defined in the script file named 'Program' is not derived from MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace EMail
 {
  class Program 
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
      {
       try
       {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpC = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        //From address to send email
        mail.From = new MailAddress("From@gmail.com");
        //To address to send email
        mail.To.Add("To@gmail.com");
        mail.Body = "This is a test mail from C# program";
        mail.Subject = "TEST";
        smtpC.Port = 587;
       //Credentials for From address
        smtpC.Credentials =(System.Net.ICredentialsByHost) new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EmailID", "password");
         smtpC.EnableSsl = true;
         smtpC.Send(mail);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully");
       Console.ReadLine();
      }
   catch (Exception e)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
   }  
  }
 }
```

Comment: not too sure been ages since i touched unity, but shouldnt could you be missing a using statement such as "mono" or "unity"

Comment: Ya I'm Using Below Code But It Came Authentication errors  like system.InvalidOperationException: SSL authentication error: RemoteCertificateNotAvailable, RemoteCertificateChainErrors.so how to solve those plz help me urjent

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually read your error message, it's told you the answer:

```
warning:The class defined in the script file named 'Program' is not derived from MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject
```

To make custom objects in Unity you must make them extend from either a ScriptableObject or a MonoBehaviour object in order to use them in your game engine. A ScriptableObject is for code that does not need to be attached to an in-game object whilst MonoBehaviour's do.

In this case as an email handler you need to use a scriptable object as it won't be attached to a scene object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using UnityEngine;
//^Make sure to include UnityEngine if you will connect to other game objects

//Extend ScriptableObject to use custom code 
public class EmailHandler extends ScriptableObject
{
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpC = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            //From address to send email
            mail.From = new MailAddress("From@gmail.com");
            //To address to send email
            mail.To.Add("To@gmail.com");
            mail.Body = "This is a test mail from C# program";
            mail.Subject = "TEST";
            smtpC.Port = 587;
            //Credentials for From address
            smtpC.Credentials =(System.Net.ICredentialsByHost) new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EmailID", "password");
            smtpC.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpC.Send(mail);

            //Change Console.Writeline to Debug.Log 
            Debug.Log ("Message sent successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.GetBaseException());
            //You don't need or use Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }  
}
```

Using this should solve your questions problem and help you in completing your class.

Comment: it Cames Authantication problem so it executes catch block is  System.InvalidOperationException: SSL authentication error: RemoteCertificateNotAvailable, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
.,plz help me.

Comment: It took me ten seconds in Google and your error says authentication issue. Read your errors. It is an authentication issue with Gmail - you haven't changed your user and password for gmail on `smtpC.Credentials =(System.Net.ICredentialsByHost) new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EmailID", "password);`

Comment: i'm given in Email id is From Mail id And password is From Mail Id Passwprd .is It Correct Or Not.

Comment: Unless the email and password you are inputting there are valid GMail user and pass it will not work

Comment: ok , so what parameters are passed in emailid , password ? so plz help me exactly what i can do i didn't clear that.

Comment: Do you have a gmail address to use in this program. An email account with GMail...

Comment: hello @Blue Sir,reply what i'm doing exactly plz help me

Comment: With all due respect I have already told you what to do - put your username and password into 

`smtpC.Credentials =(System.Net.ICredentialsByHost) new System.Net.NetworkCredential("PUT USERNAME HERE", "PUT PASSWORD HERE");`
            
I cannot make it more simple than that.

Comment: ya , i have put UserName & Password but it came Same Error thats Why i'm Asking Many More Times why it comes in this error i didn't undrstand yet.so what i can do help me.

Comment: ya this error comes putting username & password Also , Error is:System.InvalidOperationException: SSL authentication error: RemoteCertificateNotAvailable, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.<callback>m__4 (System.Object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: I'm not going to continue helping @user2632643 - this is a Q&A site and I answered your question. We are not a tech support site and won't write your code for you. Investigate it on Google, look at your errors and try other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well from Some 5min Google searches, the authentication due to certificate validation error may have a fix.
At first I simply thought Google was denying your credentials since you have had multipul attempts to connect and login.

If you on windows try running the two command provided by this posts correct answer:
[Smtp problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801224/smtpclient-with-gmail)