# Send email SMTP exception

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have this error when I try to send an email from c#

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@hotmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "pwd");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
>   The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: check if you can log into the gmail account from the computer the application is running on. Sometimes google can block access from remote computers. also check if 2 factor authentication is enabled.

Comment: Check the security settings of your Gmail account and enable less secure apps

Comment: Maybe [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801224/smtpclient-with-gmail) answers will help you

Comment: i can access my account from computer

Comment: @IslamGx Please follow this link to change the security settings https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: Access for less secure apps is on

Comment: @IslamGx what's the result / error now? Or was it enabled already, you should have mentioned that in your OP then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove these two lines

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Comment: exactly it was a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "name", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.To.Add("to@gmail.com");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
        mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
        client.Send(mail);
```