# Send email from C# does not work

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an email with C# code, copied from examples on MSDN (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// from and password contain my credentials
// to contains a valid email address
public static void CodeExample()
{
    try
    {
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to))
        {
            using (SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("smtp.googlemail.com"))
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                mail.Subject = "Test subject";
                mail.Body = "Test message";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

                server.Port = 465;
                server.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);
                server.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                server.EnableSsl = true;
                server.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
                server.Timeout = 60000;

                Console.WriteLine("Sending to {0} by using SMTP host {1} port {2}.", to.ToString(), server.Host, server.Port);

                server.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("mail Sent");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception:");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException?.ToString());
    }
}
```

But I always get an exception:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

The ‘from’ address details have been checked and seem OK. Sending from a Yahoo! account fails in the same way. I have tried lots of different combinations of `SmtpClient` properties. There are no messages in my firewall log.

Using Thunderbird, I can send from both the Googlemail and Yahoo! accounts without problems.

I would be grateful for any hints on how to get this to work.

Edit

I have seen this post [SmtpException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect)

Google mail fails on port 587 (both using and commenting-out `UseDefaultCredentials = true` and `EnableSsl = true`), reporting that I have an insecure app. I will try Yahoo! on port 587 later.

Comment: `SmtpClient server` - I like that naming convention ;p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SmtpException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net\_io\_connectionclosed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect)

Comment: use smtp client as `new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")` and assign server port the value `587`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Using port 587 was important, as shown at [SmtpException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect)

I still cannot get smtp.googlemail.com or smtp.gmail.com to work, but that is covered at [SmtpClient with Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801224/smtpclient-with-gmail).

My program is now working with smtp.mail.yahoo.com.