# Sending an Email using SMTP client

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am trying to send an email using SMTP client using my gmail credential.
This is the code am using

```
        using (var mail = GetMailInfo())
        {
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465))
            {
                    client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("**@gmail.com", "Password");
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(mail);
            }
        }
```

I receive a time out error

> The operation has timed out

If I try again I get another error saying

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Too many concurrent SMTP connections; please try again later.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You fail to read? The error message clearly states the connection was refused due to too many concurrent SMTP connections, and tells you to try later. WIth the information you provided that clearly points to the server being overloaded at the moment.

Comment: @TomTom I indeed read that. But am sending only one email one time its a time out and another time instead of time out this one comes.

Comment: And? That is not YOUR server - the SERVER may be overloaded. THAT is what it tells you. If YOU do not cause it - well, it still is overloaded. You send like someone in a traffic jam saying "why is there a traffic jam, I am only here with one car".. And, btw., one mail at a time like this is abuse of the SMTP protocol. It is not meant to have a new connection per email.

Comment: @TomTom Ok What would you suggest ?

Comment: Where did you get sample code?  Your code is using port 465 which is SSL and you probably need to use TLS port 587.  See : https://www.siteground.com/kb/google_free_smtp_server/

Comment: This can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801224/smtpclient-with-gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I figure it out what was wrong with my code
Updated code is below

```
using (var mail = GetMailInfo())
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)) // port is 587 instead of 465 as mentioned by @jdweng in the comment
        {
                client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // this must be before the **Credentials** else this will reset the given credential                   
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("**@gmail.com", "Password");
                
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
```

On the top if you are using gmail go to settings and deactivate 2 way authentification and **Access for less secure apps** should be **Activated**

All these can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)